# XNA Sprite Class using Game Component and IDrawable

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am working on my Sprite and Actor class for a game and I have 2 different types of enemies, a pumpkin and a bat. What I wanted to do was to make them both updatable so the pumpkin will fall straight down from its spawn and the bat will follow the player until the player's death or its destruction. But right now I am trying to create their Actor class and I am kind of new to XNA and Stack-Overflow.

Sprite Class:

```
public class Sprite : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent, IDrawable
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Vector2 position;
    public Vector2 moveSpeed;
    public Vector2 scale;
    public Color tint;
    public bool active;

    public Rectangle rect
    {
        get { return new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, Width, Height); }
    }
    public int Height
    {
        get { return (int)(texture.Height * scale.Y); }
    }
    public int Width
    {
        get { return (int)(texture.Width * scale.X);}
    }
    public Sprite(Game game, String tex)
        : base(game)
    {
        // TODO: Construct any child components here
        texture = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>(tex);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game component to perform any initialization it needs to before starting
    /// to run.  This is where it can query for any required services and load content.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization code here
        base.Initialize();
        position = Vector2.Zero;
        tint = Color.White;
        active = true;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game component to update itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // TODO: Add your update code here
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        ((Game1)Game).spriteBatch.Begin();
        ((Game1)Game).spriteBatch.Draw(texture,rect,tint);
        ((Game1)Game).spriteBatch.End();
    }
    public int DrawOrder
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DrawOrderChanged;
    public bool Visible
    {
        get { return active; }
    }
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> VisibleChanged;
}
```

Actor Class:

```
public class Actor : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
{
    public Sprite sprite; //Call Instance of Sprite class
    public String tag; //String for the texture
    public float health; //Health of the sprite
    public int value; //The enemies will need a score

    public Actor(Game game, String tex)
        : base(game)
    {
        // TODO: Construct any child components here
        sprite = new Sprite(game, tex);

        game.Components.Add(this);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game component to perform any initialization it needs to before starting
    /// to run.  This is where it can query for any required services and load content.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization code here

        base.Initialize();
        health = 100.0f; //Initialize the health of Enemy
        value = 10; //Initialize the value of enemy destruction
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game component to update itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // TODO: Add your update code here
        if(sprite.rect.Intersects(sprite.rect))
        {
            health -= 100;
            sprite.active = false;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your precise programming problem exactly? It's hard to tell what's your question. And by the way you can use `DrawableGameComponent` instead of both `GameComponent` and `IDrawable`.

Comment: I'm stuck on the actor class. I have no idea how to implement it or if I am actually doing it correctly, and I also was checking to see if I should put the health and value of the score for the enemies in the actor or should I use a manager for the 2 types of enemies.

Comment: Leaving them in their actor class is fine IMO. Or you could add two classes inheriting Actor for your two enemies and store their values there. I guess they'll also have different behaviors in the long run, so you'll need a way to separate them anyway. If you need inspiration for your design you can also check this great [MSDN tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx). You can download the source and take a look at it, it got pretty much everything you need to get your started and have basic explanations on the website.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, because you are right they will have different behaviors. I am also looking at the link you posted now thanks.